# Rails unaltered generated controller, worked before, now getting NoMethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my unaltered controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here are my routes:

```
  root :to => "songs#index"
  match '/votes/:song_id/:user_id' => "votes#create"
  resources :votes

  resource :session

  resources :users

  resources :songs

  match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login" 
  match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

And the error:

```
undefined method `user' for #<User:0x00000102b42a00>


Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"oOzmpsbEJtnHC4YGeAf4N6pVxfK+Zf4W9ec+0E/Eds0=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"bhjjhb@hui.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  validates_uniqueness_of :user
  validates_presence_of :password

  has_many :votes


end
```

Comment: do you have any after_save or after_create callback

Comment: What's line 45? What calls "user"?

Comment: @Dave, line 45 is respond_to do |format|, user is called by this form: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">

Comment: So, are there callbacks in the model? What calls the method "user"?

Comment: Please show the code in your user model.

Comment: You probably want a unique email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

> This helper validates that the ***attribute***’s value is unique

Your problem is in your validations; `validates_uniqueness_of` checks the uniqueness of a model attribute, so `validates_uniqueness_of :user` is trying to check that the user's `user` attribute is unique. In the process, it calls `@user.user`, which produces the `NoMethodError`.

Edited to add: As @Amar says, the way to fix this is by validating the uniqueness of some attribute or set of attributes that will be unique for each user record (such as `:email`).

Answer (score 1):

instead of `validates_uniqueness_of :user` use this `validates_uniqueness_of :email`
 validation mainly works on attribute